# Efficient way to select arrays using np.where()?

Tags: python, arrays, array-broadcasting

I have three arrays: `m`, `grad1`, and `grad2`. `m` is of the shape `(x,)` while `grad1` and `grad2` are of the shape `(x,y,z)`. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to create a new array with value entries of either `grad1` or `grad2` based on the values of `m`. I've attempted to do this using the following code:

```
param0_grad = np.where(m[:] > 0, grad1, grad2)
```

Based on my understanding of `np.where()`, I thought this should populate `param0_grad` with either `grad1` or `grad2` based on each value in `m`. However, I'm getting the following broadcasting error (when x=3, y=4, z=2):

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (3,4,2) (3,4,2)
```

The code works for x=2, but no values of x>2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
param0_grad = np.where(m[:,None,None] > 0, grad1, grad2)
```

Basically, you need to add an empty dimension for broadcasting the trailing axes.

Comment: You should also mention that numpy tries to match dimensions backwards, so when m.shape is (2,) it works because the other arrays have shapes (3, 4, 2). But that would obviously result to a different output than m[:None,None].

Comment: Yes, good point. Implicit broadcasting will only take into account the trailing dimensions, the trailing dimensions would be 2 if the shape is (2,) which coincidentally matches the last dimension in the other two arrays.

Comment: I think you meant to write m[:,None,None], which will explicitly broadcast the last two dimensions.

Comment: Yes, I missed a comma there.